# A section of my code is not working and I am not sure why (python)

Tags: python

I am a beginner at python and decided to attempt to make minesweeper. Everything seems to be working correctly, but the section of my code responsible for filling a dictionary with data on every square does not seem to be working. here is the function in question:

```
import random

n = 9
grid_values = {}
num_of_mines = 10

def int_to_str(x, y):
    list_ = [str(x), str(y)]
    z = ''.join(list_)
    return z

def generate_mines():
    global grid_values
    global revealed_values

    for a in range(num_of_mines):
        while True:
            x = random.randint(1, n)
            y = random.randint(1, n)
            if int_to_str(x, y) not in grid_values:
                grid_values[int_to_str(x, y)] = 'M'
                break
            if int_to_str(x, y) in grid_values:
                continue
    
    x = 1
    y = 1
    while True:
        if int_to_str(x, y) not in grid_values:
            #checks if the space is a mine
            m_in_radius = 0
            if int_to_str((x - 1), (y - 1)) in grid_values and grid_values.pop(int_to_str((x - 1), (y - 1))) == 'M' :
                m_in_radius += 1
            if int_to_str(x, (y - 1)) in grid_values and grid_values.pop(int_to_str(x , (y - 1))) == 'M' :
                m_in_radius += 1
            if int_to_str((x + 1), (y - 1)) in grid_values and grid_values.pop(int_to_str((x + 1), (y - 1))) == 'M' :
                m_in_radius += 1
            if int_to_str((x - 1), y) in grid_values and grid_values.pop(int_to_str((x - 1), y)) == 'M' :
                m_in_radius += 1
            if int_to_str(x, y) in grid_values and grid_values.pop(int_to_str(x , y)) == 'M' :
                m_in_radius += 1
            if int_to_str((x + 1), y) in grid_values and grid_values.pop(int_to_str((x + 1), y)) == 'M' :
                m_in_radius += 1
            if int_to_str((x - 1), (y + 1)) in grid_values and grid_values.pop(int_to_str((x - 1), (y + 1))) == 'M' :
                m_in_radius += 1
            if int_to_str(x, (y - 1)) in grid_values and grid_values.pop(int_to_str(x, (y - 1))) == 'M' :
                m_in_radius += 1
            if int_to_str((x + 1), (y + 1)) in grid_values and grid_values.pop(int_to_str((x + 1), (y + 1))) == 'M' :
                m_in_radius += 1
            grid_values[int_to_str(x, y)] = m_in_radius
            #checks every space around the specified space, puts num of mines around it as its real value

        if x == n and y == n:
            break
        if y == n:
            x += 1
            y = 0
        y += 1


generate_mines()
print(grid_values)
```

grid_values is a dictionary to store all square values and int_to_str is a function to turn 2 integers into 1 string

when I run this function and then print out grid_values, only data for the mines show up.

Comment: Please provide the expected see [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.
We also expect that you will trace the suspect values just before the point of error.   Your posted code is a function that you never call, and there's no output trace.

Comment: step 1: In the function `generate_mines()`, you don't need to have `if int_to_str(x, y) in grid_values: continue`. It is assumed to go back to while loop anyway

Comment: Step 2: In your while statement (second one), do you realize that `x` and `y` will always be `1`? I dont see you incrementing the values of `x` or `y`.

Comment: Also, can you share the code for `int_to_str(x , y)` please? Want to know what is expected out of that return statement.

Comment: Thank you feedback, I have updated the code to include the expected MRE

Comment: your pop logic to check is a dangerous one. If it is not `M`, you lose the value of the number of mines. See my answer. I am calling that out as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few problems to solve for.

1. You don't need the second if statement in this code. It is assumed that the code will go back to the while statement. You can remove it and there won't be any change to the execution.

Your code:

```
for a in range(num_of_mines):
    while True:
        x = random.randint(1, n)
        y = random.randint(1, n)
        if int_to_str(x, y) not in grid_values:
            grid_values[int_to_str(x, y)] = 'M'
            break
        if int_to_str(x, y) in grid_values:
            continue
```

2. Your if statement is not correct. Looks like you want to check if the values is not in the grid values. Instead change it to `if int_to_str(x, y) not in grid_values` Read more about this [here](https://thispointer.com/python-how-to-check-if-a-key-exists-in-dictionary/)

Your code:

```
x = 1
y = 1
while True:
    if int_to_str(x, y) in grid_values == False:
```

3. I would modify the function `int_to_str(x, y)` to just one line

`return str(x) + str(y)`. You don't need to put the values into a list and do a join. This will take care of it. There is no problem with the function but I think this will be much easier.

4. Irrespective of whether the value of the pop `== 'M'` or not, the element will get popped out. So the code that eventually puts a value `grid_values[int_to_str(x, y)] = m_in_radius` is getting lost due to the `pop`. Is that your intention? You may want to revisit how you are doing the pop to check for `M`. Instead, you may want to check if the value is `M` first, and if so, pop and increment `m_in_radius`.

One way to do that would be `if grid_value.get(int_to_str(x, y), 'X') == 'M'`, if the key exists and value is `M`, it will return `M` else whatever is in the value. If the key did not exist, it will return `X`.

See if this code is useful to you :

```
import random
grid_values = {}
for a in range(12):
    while True:
        x = random.randint(1, 9)
        y = random.randint(1, 9)
        if str(x)+str(y) not in grid_values:
            grid_values[str(x)+str(y)] = 'M'
            break
print (grid_values)
#x, y = 1,1
for x in range (1, 10):
    for y in range (1, 10):
        m_in_radius = 0
        for i in [-1,0,1]:
            for j in [-1,0,1]:
                if grid_values.get(str(x+i)+str(y+j), 'X') == 'M':
                    #grid_values.pop(str(x+i)+str(y+j))  
                    #don't pop it. You can keep the value for reference
                    #print (str(x+i)+str(y+j),'M')
                    m_in_radius += 1
        if grid_values.get(str(x)+str(y), 'X') != 'M':
            grid_values[str(x)+str(y)] = m_in_radius

#printing the 9x9 matrix with Mines & # of mines

for x in range (1, 10):
    for y in range (1, 10):
        print (str(grid_values.get(str(x)+str(y),'X')), end = ' ')
    print()
```

Here is an output I got for plotting 12 mines:

```
{'38': 'M', '41': 'M', '47': 'M', '73': 'M', '32': 'M', '92': 'M', '16': 'M', '87': 'M', '72': 'M', '54': 'M', '81': 'M', '79': 'M'}

0 0 0 0 1 M 1 0 0 
1 1 1 0 1 1 2 1 1 
2 M 1 0 0 1 2 M 1 
M 2 2 1 1 1 M 2 1 
1 1 1 M 1 1 1 1 0 
1 2 3 2 1 0 0 1 1 
2 M M 1 0 1 1 2 M 
M 4 3 1 0 1 M 2 1 
2 M 1 0 0 1 1 1 0
```

One for 4 mines:

```
{'87': 'M', '83': 'M', '19': 'M', '66': 'M'}

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 M 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 
0 0 0 0 1 M 1 0 0 
0 1 1 1 1 2 2 1 0 
0 1 M 1 0 1 M 1 0 
0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0
```

And another for 5 mines:

```
{'68': 'M', '78': 'M', '77': 'M', '42': 'M', '76': 'M'}

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 
1 M 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 
1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 
0 0 0 0 1 2 4 M 2 
0 0 0 0 1 M M M 2 
0 0 0 0 1 2 3 2 1 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: Thank you! I have no idea why I used pop and completely overlooked it

Answer (score 0):

You should put parenthesis i.e. `(int_to_str(x, y) in grid_values) == False` or better yet you should write it as `int_to_str(x, y) not in grid_values`.

When you're writing it as you did, it's **operator chaining**. Meaning, `int_to_str(x, y) in grid_values == False` is equivalent to `int_to_str(x, y) in grid_values and grid_values == False`.

Comment: Thank you for answering! However when I changed the if statement it still did not work, when printing out the grid_values dictionary only 1 pair appeared.

Comment: @MatthewKim, the problems in your code are many. I called out 2 of them. First fix the x and y issue